# SpriteKit/Swift - Binary Operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'CGVector' operands

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my game I need to compare the 2 speeds upon a collision. Both speeds are in the CGVector(dx: , dy:) format. However Swift 3 doesn't let me use the '>' and '<' operands to compare them. How can I solve this? Code is as follows:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    let ballNode = self.childNode(withName: ballName)
    let defaultSpeedX:CGFloat = 100
    let defaultSpeedY:CGFloat = -100
    let maxSpeed = CGVector(dx: defaultSpeedX * 3, dy: defaultSpeedY * 3)
    let minSpeed = CGVector(dx: defaultSpeedX / 2 , dy: defaultSpeedY / 2)

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == drainBitmask {
        endGame()

    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == target1Bitmask {
        score += 20
        self.vc.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        let currentSpeedX = ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx
        let currentSpeedY = ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy
        let speedDouble = CGVector(dx: currentSpeedX! * 2, dy: currentSpeedY! * 2)

        if ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity == maxSpeed {

            ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = maxSpeed

        } else if speedDouble < maxSpeed {

            ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = speedDouble

        } else if speedDouble > maxSpeed {

            ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = maxSpeed

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "speed" of the vector is actually the hypotenuse of the triangle your vector describes. Try this:

```
extension CGVector {
    var speed: CGFloat {
        return hypot(dx, dy)
    }

    static func > (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> Bool {
        return lhs.speed > rhs.speed
    }

    static func < (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> Bool {
        return lhs.speed < rhs.speed
    }
}

let aaa = CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10)
let bbb = CGVector(dx: 13, dy: 12)

print(aaa > bbb)
```

With this extension in place, you'll find your existing code, `} else if speedDouble < maxSpeed {`, will compile.

How does it work? Well, your speed as a vector is defined with two components - a horizontal speed, `dx`, and a vertical speed, `dy`. If you imagine `dx` and `dy` as the two side of a right angled triangle, the length of the vector is the hypotenuse (remember Pythagorus) - that's what `hypot` returns.

With the extension above, the `<` and `>` operators now compare a `CGVector` object's speed (which you could happily rename `length`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply however Im confused as to how I would implement this in my code ? How could I use it in the didBegin(contact) ?

Comment: you are extending CGVector so that it recognizes the > operator (because what does a vector > vector really mean?  You need to define this)

Comment: @John_Sm1 this is an `extension` which is a magical aspect of Swift and allows you to customise the language to make it do what you want, how you want. And the limits of this ability aren't much. Combined with TypeAliases (new names you can invent and give to types throughout your code) you can merge these abilities with custom functions that "reinvent" functionality in almost whatever syntax and verbiage you like. Swift is the new Logo, almost.